# UITableView - iPad - Property '' Not Found on Object of type UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have added a UITableView prototype Cell into a UIView for an iPad application using StoryBoard in Xcode (targeting iOS6).

The problem I'm having is that the labels are not being recognized in my viewController when I try to reference them.

In my implementation, I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dashboardMessage";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    int row = [indexPath row];


       cell.messageSender.text = [_matches valueForKey:@"from"];

}
```

The last line is causing an error:  Property 'messageSender' Not Found on Object of type UITableViewCell

In the cell's header file I have:

```
@interface DashboardMessageCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageSender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageDescr;
```

and the header file is imported into the viewController.

I'm lost as to what can be causing the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your cell must be DashboardMessageCell your code could be like this:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dashboardMessage";
DashboardMessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[DashboardMessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
   }
   int row = [indexPath row];
   cell.messageSender.text = [_matches valueForKey:@"from"];
}
```

I din't try this code
I hope it will help you

Comment: Awesome, it's not crashing anymore. Thanks!